# How to handle configuration IConfiguration settings classes with C# 8 nullable enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration, nullable

What is the best way to handle mandatory configuration settings with `IConfiguraion` and C# 8's nullable enabled?

I get many warnings e.g. `CS8618`. I'd rather not duplicate all settings classes and validating all fields are non-null.

The best "trick" I've found is to issue a `#nullable disable` in the file that holds all the configuration classes.

Background
When using `IConfiguration` and declaring configuration classes that take on values from json files. For example I have a configuration file with the following mandatory settings.

```
public class ServiceSpecificSettings
{
    public string LastRunTimestampPath { get; set; }
    public LogFilterSettings LogFilter { get; set; }
}

public class LogFilterSettings
{
    public ApplicationsSettings ApplicationLog { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationsSettings
{
    public SourceSettings Sources { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, bool> Levels { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can try to check if your csproj file contains `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`,if so,remove it.

Comment: I want to use the nullable feature of the language